# How to change text color while hovering around border in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I'm new to developing! I started learning a few months ago :D
I'm trying to make it so when I hover around a div that contains a header and some text, then a border colored in a different way than the background will pop up around it, highlighting the area of that div.
I've been successful with that!

```
.item {
    border: solid 0px;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    background: rgba(164, 165, 219, 0.45);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.item:hover {
    background: rgba(72, 74, 196, 0.45);
}
```

However, I can't seem to be able to change the color of the text as well.
I can only change the color of the text when hovering directly above it.

```
.project-text {
    color: rgb(43, 41, 41);
    font-size: 50px;
}

.project-text:hover {
    color: white;

}
```

I want to be able to change the color of the text already while hovering around the border of the div, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML, ideally as [mre].

Comment: Basically, as Manjuboyz given the answer, you just need to add "color: white" in " .item:hover " style along with background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `.project-text` is inside of `.item`. You can create a CSS selector to that styles the children based on hover state of the parent.  See commented code below; I added a padding on `.item` to better show the result.

```css
.item {
    border: solid 0px;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    background: rgba(164, 165, 219, 0.45);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 2rem /* two times the font size of the body */
}

.item:hover {
    background: rgba(72, 74, 196, 0.45);
}

.project-text {
    color: rgb(43, 41, 41);
    font-size: 50px;
}

.item:hover .project-text { /* changed selector */
    color: white;

}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <p class="project-text">
    Hello
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're asking?

I just added extra `background-color` for the `hover` feel free to remove that.

```css
#mainDiv {
   height: 30px;
   width: 100px;
   border:1px solid black;
   font-size:bold;
   text-align:center;
   padding:4px;
   color:red;
}

#mainDiv:hover {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: teal;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  Hover here
</div>
```